# How to set the rails form helper radio_button to a check settings in a controller#new action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller:

**Groups**

```
def new
 @group = Group.new
 @group.password_required = (params[:type]== 1) ? false : true
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for @group, :format => :json, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :password_required, '0' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :password_required, '1' %>
<% end %>
```

Why isn't the radio button with the password_required value set in the controller showing up as checked when the view renders in the browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you access a new group page, you've passed params[:type], so you just change value from '0' to false and '1' to true.

You get params[:type]'s value as a String, so you have to change value from 1 to '1'.

```
@group.password_required = (params[:type] == '1') ? false : true
```

## View

```
<%= form_for @group, :format => :json, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :password_required, false %>
  <%= f.radio_button :password_required, true %>
<% end %>
```